# Order of address component in google places api

Tags: geocoding, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I want to know the order of address_component returned by google places api ,which type goes to top is it route or street_address or any other that I might be missing of the mentioned types in **Additional types returned by the Places service** https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

Answer (score 1):

Order of address components changes across results.

Generally speaking, the order is from more to less specific. First components identify the building/number, then street/block part of the address, then postal and political features follow. The order is "mostly" by size but address formatting peculiarities can introduce variations; e.g. `postal_code` comes after `country` in Japan.

This applies to [Table 2: Additional types returned by the Places service](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table2) in the Places API and [Address Types and Address Component Types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Types) in the Geocoding API.

There is no particular order when it comes to the establishments types ([Table 1: Types supported in place search and addition](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table1)).

Comment: @Subject: please make proper use of comments. For posterity, here's yours: "This is nowhere near enough information to get specific data out of the list, what do I do if I want to get just the city, or just the country ?!?!?!?!?!" ─ I will answer shortly.

Comment: @Subject: the country is very easy, just find the address component with "country" in its types array. The city may be easy or not, depending on the country (or even smaller region), please see the explanation in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

Answer (score 0):

The only real way is to loop over the address components array and then over the type array inside the component. This is the code I use to get an 'address object' with the details I need:

```
function addressFromGooglePlace(place){
    let address = {
        line1: null,
        city: null,
        state: null,
        postcode: null,
        country: null
    };

    let streetNumber = null;
    let street = null;

    if(typeof place === 'object' && typeof place.address_components === 'object' && Array.isArray(place.address_components)){
        place.address_components.forEach((c) => {
            if(typeof c === 'object' && typeof c.types === 'object' && Array.isArray(c.types)){
                c.types.forEach((t) => {
                    switch(t){
                        case 'postal_code':
                            if(address.postcode === null){
                                if(typeof c.long_name !== 'undefined'){
                                    address.postcode = c.long_name
                                } else if(typeof c.short_name !== 'undefined'){
                                    address.postcode = c.short_name
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'country':
                            if(address.country === null){
                                if(typeof c.long_name !== 'undefined'){
                                    address.country = c.long_name
                                } else if(typeof c.short_name !== 'undefined'){
                                    address.country = c.short_name
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'administrative_area_level_1':
                            if(address.state === null){
                                if(typeof c.long_name !== 'undefined'){
                                    address.state = c.long_name
                                } else if(typeof c.short_name !== 'undefined'){
                                    address.state = c.short_name
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'locality':
                            if(address.state === null){
                                if(typeof c.long_name !== 'undefined'){
                                    address.city = c.long_name
                                } else if(typeof c.short_name !== 'undefined'){
                                    address.city = c.short_name
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'street_number':
                            if(streetNumber === null){
                                if(typeof c.long_name !== 'undefined'){
                                    streetNumber = c.long_name
                                } else if(typeof c.short_name !== 'undefined'){
                                    streetNumber = c.short_name
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'route':
                            if(street === null){
                                if(typeof c.short_name !== 'undefined'){
                                    street = c.short_name
                                } else if(typeof c.long_name !== 'undefined'){
                                    street = c.long_name
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        if(streetNumber === null){
            address.line1 = street;
        } else {
            if(street === null){
                address.line1 = streetNumber
            } else {
                address.line1 = streetNumber+' '+street;
            }
        }
        return address;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Just feed the function a place and it should sniff out the details. Keep in mind I designed this to work with Australian addresses but it should also work with US addresses (excluding line2).